# PostgreSQL WITH query on already selected table

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I use PostgreSQL `WITH` [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html). And I can run pretty complicated query, but can I use already sorted data? For instance:

```
SELECT id, f_name, l_name, email FROM users
WHERE f_name = 'BabyBoy'

WITH i_need_do_thomething AS (
# and than use that filtered data
)
SELECT * FROM i_need_do_thomething
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

All problems that I use this query in Ruby on Rails. And I use association like:

```
@laptop = Laptop.find(1)
@laptop.user.do_custom_sql(HERE_WILL_BE_RAW_SQL)
```

where `@laptop.user` is equal to

```
SELECT id, f_name, l_name, email FROM users
WHERE f_name = 'BabyBoy'
```

Answer (score 2):

Each query on `WITH QUERIES` is treated like a temporary table. You can place as many queries as you need:

```
WITH filtered_something AS (
    SELECT id, f_name, l_name, email FROM users WHERE f_name = 'BabyBoy'
), i_need_do_something AS (
    SELECT * FROM filtered_something
)
SELECT * FROM i_need_do_something;
```

Comment: so I can use `WITH` ONLY in a separate case? And I can't use it as I wrote in the example. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can't do it this way. In this case I think you should use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(entire_sql_here)` and then iterate over result set.